# About DEMUX/demultiplexer: can any Boolean function be realized with the help of demultiplexers?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, boolean-algebra

I know that as we OR the outputs of a DEMUX we can get a function as the first screenshot which states that an OR gate generates the one-set of the function.

[image]

But can any Boolean function be realized with the help of demultiplexers?

Comment: How does your lecture define "boolean function"? How does it relate to the Y column of the table?

Comment: @CL. y(a,b,c) = the minterms.  It is defined like that. So if we OR the outputs of the DEMUX that are 1, can we do that for every Boolean Function using demux and an OR Gate? Or, are there any limitations to it?

Comment: Yes, any Boolean function be realized with the help of demultiplexers

Comment: Is there any boolean function that can *not* described by such a table?

Comment: You can even describe ... sequential (with "memory") functions. I did this when describing an 8 stages elevator  ... and using also read-only memory (old EPROM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is yes.
for you to be able to generate any Boolean function, you have to be able to generate three gates: AND, OR, NOT.
OR can be generated with a DEMUX as demonstrated,

let's generate AND:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMIpR7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

now we generate NOT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXeboI.png)</sup>